# Using a 2D array in an equation

Tags: c++, arrays

Recently I've been working on an engine thrust that calculates slope at the given values.

I've gotten a lot of the code to work, but I cant seem to get the equation function working. The person is supposed to list values based off specific points on a graph and the newton, and then give a time thats different and the computer will find a value in between the time given and do a slope calculation.

Of course thats not working and I'm really lost at this point, I'm 100% sure my loop is wrong in the function, but I'm not sure my equation is wrong.

Basically the program is supposed to do this

```
x   y
.19 14.5
.24  6.0
.40  4.4

Enter a time: .21

((.21-.19)/.24-.19))*(6-14.5)+14.5=11.1

the thrust at time .21 is 11.1
```

**Source**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

const int grid_rows=50;
const int grid_cols=2;

double slope(double thrust[grid_rows][grid_cols],double time);

// Constant Declarations
const double PI = 3.1415926535; // the radius/diameter of a circle

// Main Program
int main( )
{
 system("CLS");
 cout << "Take Home #12 by - "
    << "CETUA\n\n";

double thrust[grid_rows][grid_cols];
double time;
double newton;
char ans;
int i=0;
int j=0;

cout << "Enter thrust curve data (0 for thrust end list): "<<endl;
for(i=0;i < grid_rows; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j< grid_cols;j++)
    {
        cin >> thrust[i][j];
        if(thrust[i][j]==0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(thrust[i][j]==0)
    {
        break;
    }
  }


  do
  {
    cout << "Enter a time: "<<endl;
    cin >> time;

    newton=slope(thrust,time);

    cout << "The thrust at time "<<time << " is " << newton << " newtons."                 <<endl:
    cout << "Would you like another thrust value? (Y or N): " <<endl;
    cin >> ans;
  }while(ans=='Y'||ans=='y');
}

double slope(double thrust[50][2],double time)
{
  double newton;

  while(time > thrust[50][2]);
  {
    for(int i=0;i < grid_rows; i++)
    {
      for( int j=0; j< grid_cols;j++)
      {
        newton=((time - thrust[i][j])/(thrust[i][j]-thrust[i][j]))
            *(thrust[i][j]-thrust[i][j])+thrust[i][j];
        return newton;
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Try to indent the code before post, it makes code is more readable.

Comment: give me your example in array representation, is it 3X2 ?

Comment: its a 50*2, 50 rows, and 2 columns

Comment: wouldn't the slope() method exit the first time (when i=j=0) when you call "returns newton;". why would you need 50x2 matrix then?

Comment: no because I insert values where i=0, and j =0 are, its only when I type in zero that it ends it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double slope(double thrust[50][2],double time)
{
  double newton;

  while(time > thrust[50][2]);
  {
    for(int i=0;i < grid_rows; i++)
    {
      for( int j=0; j< grid_cols;j++)
      {
        newton=((time - thrust[i][j])/(thrust[i][j]-thrust[i][j]))
            *(thrust[i][j]-thrust[i][j])+thrust[i][j];
        return newton; 
      }
    }
   }
 }
```

i see a few problems with your algo.

1)you get divide by zero error here.

```
((time - thrust[i][j])/(thrust[i][j]-thrust[i][j]))
```

2) your loop will never run (always return on first iteration).

```
return newton;
```

3) if you fix (2) remember that you may be forever trapped in while loop, (value of time and thrust[50][2] was never changed).

also is the ";" at the end of the while loop deliberate?

```
while(time > thrust[50][2]);
```

you may want to change your slope method to the following.

```
double slope (double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2, double time){

    double result = 0;
    if ((x2-x1) != 0 ){ // google 'double comparison" you may want to use EPSILON instead
        result = ((time - x1)/(x2-x1)) * (y2-y1) + y1
    } 
    return result;
}
```

to use it you probably want to do some thing along the following.

```
... assuming trust 
    [row][0] contains all the x
    [row][1] contains all the y
    double [lastEntry-1] results;
for(int i=0; i< lastEntry-1; i++){

    results[i] = slope ( thrust[i][0],  //x1
                         thrust[i+1][0],//x2
                         thrust[i][1],  //y1
                         thrust[i+1][1],//y2 
                         time);
}
```

I leave how to populate thrust from cin as an exercise for you.

Comment: hmm, so how would i tell the program which part of the array is for what part of the function?